# Dynamically replacing a panel of buttons

Tags: java, swing

This is my first trial in java Swing. The issue am having is recreating the calendar panel every time the month changes. I would like to have the panelRightDown repopulated when addMonth is called (when > or < is clicked). I have tried calling revalidate, invalidate, repaint in addMonth but everything just goes haywire. The same methods ought to be implemented while calculating the year. Any help would be appreciated. More so, a better approach to this is highly welcome.

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {   
    private final int windowWidth = 700;
    private final int windowHeight = 600;
    private final Container container;
    private final JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel panelRight = new JPanel();
    private final GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    private final int verticalSpacerSize = 8;
    private final int horizontalSpacerSize = 15;
    private Border lowerEtchedBorder = 
            BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED);

    // -----
    protected boolean controlsOnTop;
    protected boolean removeOnDaySelection;

    protected Calendar currentDisplayDate;

    protected JButton prevMonth;
    protected JButton nextMonth;
    protected JButton prevYear;
    protected JButton nextYear;

    protected JTextField textField;

    protected List<ActionListener> popupListeners = 
        new ArrayList<ActionListener>();

    protected Popup popup;

    protected SimpleDateFormat dayName   = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
    protected SimpleDateFormat monthName = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");

    protected String iconFile = "datepicker.gif";
    protected String[] weekdayNames = 
        {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
    JPanel datePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelRightDown = new JPanel();
    JPanel controlsPanel;
    // -----

    // Constructor to setup the GUI components and event handlers
    public Gui() {
        //-----
        currentDisplayDate   = Calendar.getInstance();
        controlsOnTop        = true;
        removeOnDaySelection = true;
        //createPanel();

        // Retrieve the content-pane of the top-level container JFrame
        // All operations done on the content-pane

        container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //container.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(windowWidth, windowHeight));
        createMenuBar();
        createStatusBar();

        JPanel fullPane = new JPanel();
        fullPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        // Spacer
        container.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(
                4), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(fullPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        fullPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(windowWidth, windowHeight));

        // Position Left and Right panels
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.3;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        fullPane.add(panelLeft, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0;
        fullPane.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(
                15), gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.9;
        fullPane.add(panelRight, gridBagConstraints);


        configurePanelLeft(panelLeft);
        configurePanelRight(panelRight);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Prod - Reminder"); 
        setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        addWindowListener(new Terminator());
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        currentDisplayDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        editDate(date);
    }

    public void setDate(Calendar date) {
        currentDisplayDate = date;
        //createPanel();
        validate();
        repaint();
    }

    public void setDate(int month, int day, int year) {
        currentDisplayDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentDisplayDate.set(expandYear(year), month - 1, day);
        //createPanel();
        validate();
        repaint();
    }

    protected int expandYear(int year) {
        if (year < 100) {                   // 2 digit year
            int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int current2DigitYear = currentYear % 100;
            int currentCentury    = currentYear / 100 * 100;
            // set 2 digit year range +20 / -80 from current year
            int high2DigitYear    = (current2DigitYear + 20) % 100;
            if (year <= high2DigitYear) {
                year += currentCentury;
            }
            else {
                year += (currentCentury - 100);
            }
        }
        return year;
    }

    public void setControlsOnTop(boolean flag) {
        controlsOnTop = flag; 
        //createPanel();
        repaint();
    }

    public Calendar getCalendarDate() {
        return currentDisplayDate;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return currentDisplayDate.getTime();
    }

    public String getFormattedDate() {
        return Integer.toString(getMonth()) + "/" + 
            Integer.toString(getDay()) + "/" +
            Integer.toString(getYear());
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return currentDisplayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return currentDisplayDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return currentDisplayDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }

    protected JPanel createControls() {        
        JPanel c = new JPanel();
        c.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        c.setFocusable(true);
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        prevYear = new JButton("<<");
        c.add(prevYear);
        prevYear.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        prevYear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                addYear(-1);        
            }
        });

        prevMonth = new JButton("<");
        c.add(prevMonth);
        prevMonth.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        prevMonth.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                addMonth(-1);       
            }
        });


        textField = new JTextField(getFormattedDate(), 10);
        c.add(textField);
        textField.setEditable(true);
        textField.setEnabled(true);
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                editDate(textField.getText());
            }
        });


        nextMonth = new JButton(">");
        c.add(nextMonth);
        nextMonth.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        nextMonth.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                addMonth(+1);   
            }
        });

        nextYear = new JButton(">>");
        c.add(nextYear);
        nextYear.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        nextYear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                addYear(+1);    
            }
        });

        return c;
    }

    protected JPanel configureDatePicker() {
        GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c  = new GridBagConstraints();

        datePanel.setFocusable(true);
        datePanel.setLayout(gridbag);

        String month = monthName.format(currentDisplayDate.getTime());
        String year  = Integer.toString(getYear());

        c.gridx      = 0;
        c.gridy      = 0;
        c.gridwidth  = 7;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        JLabel title = new JLabel(month + " " + year);
        datePanel.add(title, c);
        Font font      = title.getFont();
//        Font titleFont = new Font(font.getName(), font.getStyle(),
//              font.getSize() + 2);
        Font weekFont = new Font(font.getName(), font.getStyle(),
                font.getSize() - 2);
        title.setFont(font);

        c.gridy      = 1;
        c.weightx    = 0.1;
        c.weighty    = 0.1;
        c.gridwidth  = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        for (c.gridx = 0; c.gridx < 7; c.gridx++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(
                    weekdayNames[c.gridx], SwingConstants.CENTER);
            datePanel.add(label, c);
            label.setFont(weekFont);
        }

        Calendar draw = (Calendar) currentDisplayDate.clone();
        draw.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        draw.add(Calendar.DATE, -draw.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 1);
        int monthInt = currentDisplayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
//      monthInt = 0;
//      System.out.println("Current month: " + monthInt);

        c.gridwidth  = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        int width    = getFontMetrics(weekFont).stringWidth(" Wed ");
        int width1   = getFontMetrics(weekFont).stringWidth("Wed");
        int height   = getFontMetrics(weekFont).getHeight() + 
                (width - width1);

        for (c.gridy = 2; c.gridy < 8; c.gridy++) {
            for (c.gridx = 0; c.gridx < 7; c.gridx++) {
                JButton dayButton;
//              System.out.print("Draw month: " + draw.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                if (draw.get(Calendar.MONTH) == monthInt) {
                    String dayString = dayName.format(draw.getTime());
                    if (draw.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < 10) {
                        dayString = " " + dayString;
                    }

                    dayButton = new JButton(dayString);
                } else {
                    dayButton = new JButton();
                    dayButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
//              System.out.println(", day: " + dayName.format(draw.getTime()));
                datePanel.add(dayButton, c);
                Color color = dayButton.getBackground();
                if ((draw.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == getDay()) &&
                        (draw.get(Calendar.MONTH) == monthInt)) { 
                    dayButton.setBackground(Color.yellow);
//                  dayButton.setFocusPainted(true);
//                  dayButton.setSelected(true);
                } else
                    dayButton.setBackground(color);
                dayButton.setFont(weekFont);
                dayButton.setFocusable(true);
                //dayButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                //dayButton.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
                dayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        changeDay(e.getActionCommand());
                    }

                });
                //if (dateChange != null)
                //    dayButton.addActionListener(dateChange);
                draw.add(Calendar.DATE, +1);
            }
//          if (draw.get(Calendar.MONTH) != monthInt) break;
        }
        return datePanel;
    }

    public void addMonth(int month) {
        currentDisplayDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        datePanel.invalidate();
        controlsPanel.invalidate();
        panelRightDown.validate();

        datePanel = configureDatePicker();
        controlsPanel = createControls();

        panelRightDown.removeAll();
        panelRightDown.add(controlsPanel);
        panelRightDown.add(datePanel);
        validate();
        repaint();
    }

    public void addYear(int year) {
        currentDisplayDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        validate();
        repaint();
    }

    public void editDate(String date) {
        parseDate(date);
        //createPanel();
        validate();
        repaint();
    }

    protected void parseDate(String date) {
        String[] parts = date.split("/");
        switch (parts.length) {
            case 3:
                currentDisplayDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,
                        Integer.valueOf(parts[0]) - 1);
                currentDisplayDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                        Integer.valueOf(parts[1]));
                currentDisplayDate.set(Calendar.YEAR,
                        expandYear(Integer.valueOf(parts[2])));
                break;
            case 2:
                currentDisplayDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                currentDisplayDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,
                        Integer.valueOf(parts[0]) - 1);
                currentDisplayDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                        Integer.valueOf(parts[1]));
                break;
            default:
                // invalid date
                currentDisplayDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void changeDay(String day) {
        currentDisplayDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 
                Integer.valueOf(day.trim()));
        textField.setText(getFormattedDate());
        if (!removeOnDaySelection) {
            //createPanel();
            //validate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private void createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

        JMenuItem eMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        eMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        eMenuItem.setToolTipText("Exit application");
        eMenuItem.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.exit(0);
        });

        file.add(eMenuItem);

        menubar.add(file);

        setJMenuBar(menubar);
    }

    private void createStatusBar() {
        // create the status bar panel and shove it down the bottom of the frame
        JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
        statusPanel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        container.add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        statusPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(container.getWidth(), 20));
        statusPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(statusPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("status");
        statusLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        statusPanel.add(statusLabel);
    }

    public void configurePanelLeft(JPanel panel) {
        // Configure Left-side panels
        // Top panel
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.3;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 0.3;
        JPanel panelLeftTop = new JPanel();
        panelLeftTop.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.YELLOW));

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(panelLeftTop, gridBagConstraints);

        // Display Area
        JTextArea displayItem = new JTextArea("Hello, left top!");
        displayItem.setBorder(lowerEtchedBorder);
        displayItem.setLineWrap(true);
        displayItem.setBackground(panel.getBackground());
        displayItem.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        //displayItem.setEditable(false);
        panelLeftTop.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JScrollPane topScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        topScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(3);
        topScrollPane.setViewportView(displayItem);
        topScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        panelLeftTop.add(topScrollPane);

        // Spacer
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 0;
        panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(
                verticalSpacerSize), gridBagConstraints);

        // Bottom panel
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 0.7;
        JPanel panelLeftDown = new JPanel();
        panelLeftDown.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLUE));
        panelLeftDown.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
            gridBagConstraints.gridy = i;
            gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.3;
            //gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
            String textValue = "Area: "+ i 
                    +" This is a very long wrapped text, "
                    + "which I expect to be an example of text in a label. "
                    + "I really hope it works well."
                    + "The Scroll Bar comes when your text goes beyond "
                    + "the bounds of your view area. "
                    + "Don't use Absolute Positioning, for such a small "
                    + "talk at hand, always prefer Layout Managers, "
                    + "do read the first para of the first link, "
                    + "to know the advantage of using a Layout Manager.";
            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(textValue);
            textArea.setBorder(lowerEtchedBorder);
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setBackground(panel.getBackground());
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    displayItem.setText(textValue);
                    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() { 
                            topScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                }
            });
            panelLeftDown.add(textArea, gridBagConstraints);
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panelLeftDown,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        panelLeftDown.setAutoscrolls(true);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,800));
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(3);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
                scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
            }
         });
        panel.add(scrollPane, gridBagConstraints);

    }

    public void configurePanelRight(JPanel panel) {
        // Configure right-side panels   
        // Top panel
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 0.1;
        JPanel panelRightTop = new JPanel();
        panelRightTop.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.YELLOW));
        panelRightTop.add(new JLabel("Hello, right top!"));
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(panelRightTop, gridBagConstraints);

        // Spacer
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 0;
        panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(
                verticalSpacerSize), gridBagConstraints);

        // Bottom panel
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 0.9;

        panelRightDown.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLUE));
        //panelRightDown.add(new JLabel("Hello, right down!"));
        panel.add(panelRightDown, gridBagConstraints);
        panel.add(panelRightDown, gridBagConstraints);

        // Date Picker
        gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 0.1;
        panelRightDown.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        datePanel = configureDatePicker();
        controlsPanel = createControls();
        panelRightDown.add(controlsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelRightDown.add(datePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private ListCellRenderer<? super String> getRenderer() {
        return new DefaultListCellRenderer(){
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
                    Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean cellHasFocus) {
                JLabel listCellRendererComponent = 
                        (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                                list, value, index, isSelected,cellHasFocus);
                listCellRendererComponent.setBorder(
                        lowerEtchedBorder);
                listCellRendererComponent.setEnabled(true);
                return listCellRendererComponent;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Run the GUI construction in the Event-Dispatching thread for thread-safety
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Gui(); // Let the constructor do the job
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the problem is that you're reusing the same `JPanel`. The `datePanel` variable is always maintained as a reference to the same `JPanel`. One thing you could try is to do this in the `addMonth` method: `datePanel = new JPanel(); datePanel = configureDatePicker();`

Comment: Yes, yes yes,... Thank you Titus. That fixed it.

Comment: Great. I'm glad I could help.